# Non-prediction Applications of Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

`Prediction` seems to be the dominant theme of `machine learning`. Most algorithms have `fit` and `predict` functions so that model can be created which can predict outcomes or other parameters of interest from new set of features.

What are `non-prediction applications` of machine learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious applications are indeed the supervised learning approaches (surrogate models, prediction). But there is much more than that! Other usual applications include:

- **Clustering**: This can be seen as a different kind of prediction, but not in the classic supervised learning fashion. For instance, I have been using a clustering algorithm on a 3D geometry (CAD file) to make almost adjacent elements become actually aligned.
- **Anomaly detection**
- **Study of extreme values** (how to learn the behaviour of extreme values without actually observing such values)
- **Feature importance** (determine which sets of features impacts the result the most) or, more generally, **data mining**
- **Inference** (use a dataset to improve the prior model prediction)

Of course, most of these applications are more or less close to prediction, but not *trivial* prediction.

Answer (score 1):

These algorithms mostly are in classification such as SVM or using the result of clustering, and some learning method such as reinforcement learning. Although the nature of the ML is learning and finally you should predict something, it is not that all as you found. Some algorithms such as **evolutionary algorithms** exist in ML that are used to optimization problems and finally give you the optimization points of a target function which predict something in the middle of the algorithm, but finally give you the  optimization points and there is not any `predict` on their final results (in contract with classifications and learning algorithms).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already stated uses of machine learning, I.e. clustering, outleir analysis, etc , machine learning is also used to understand complex machine learning models. The point is that many complex machine learning models (like ensemble learning, deep neural networks,etc) often achieve better accuracy than simpler models (like logistic regression and other linear models) but are very hard to interpret. In some applications (especially fintech) it is very important to understand why a certain instance was classified as a certain class. Moreover, this approach may also help in debugging the model further. LIME and SHAP are among such algorithms.